# Camera directory null

Tags: java, android, io

I have problems reading images path url from my sd card.

It always return this error : Attempt to get length of null array: Attempt to get length of null array

Browsing images on my phone I get this directory as a camera roll directory :

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/imageName
```

I put in my manifest file permissions:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is my code :

```
 public void processImages() {
    listOfImages = new ArrayList<>();

    Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    if (isSDPresent) {


//returns same path -  /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/
        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath()+"/Camera/";
        File f = new File(path);

        listOfImages = scanPhotos(f);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "sd not present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public List<File> scanPhotos(File directory) {
    List<File> listOfPictures = new ArrayList<>();

//this returns null
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : files
                ) {
            if (file.isDirectory() && !file.isHidden()) {
                listOfPictures.addAll(scanPhotos(file));
            } else {
                if (file.getName().endsWith(".jpg") || file.getName().endsWith(".jpeg") || file.getName().endsWith(".png")) {
                    listOfPictures.add(file);
                }
            }
        }

    return listOfPictures;
}
```

Doing

```
f.canRead() - returns false
```

Comment: Did you checked Runtime permissions?

Comment: This solved my problem. I totally forgot about those Marshmallow permission.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as answer. From *marshmallow* onwards you need to provide Runtime `permissions`.

There is a callback

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {}
```

which tell permission is granted by user or not.

For adding Request permission use this [tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2016/04/obtaining-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow-6-0/).